# Tkinter application window in front of Chromium in Kiosk mode

Tags: python, linux, chromium, kiosk, tkinter

On my Raspberry Pi I have created a tkinter application with one button and configured Chromium to start in kiosk mode.

In my python application I set the following:

```
root.lift()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

But the window of my application is only in front of any other window when I start the other applications normally. When i start Chromium in full-screen or kiosk mode my application window is not displayed in front of chromium.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with wmctrl. Every 60 seconds i switch to my python window.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.